# Finding counterexamples for a "Horn" solver object

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm trying to learn how to write code for giving a counterexample to a horn clause and it's guessed interpretation. In the below code, let I be the uninterpreted function (it's a trivial loop invariant). The first 3 s.add() add the condition requirements for I(x), and the fourth one is a guess candidate for I. I try to use the s.prove directive to get a counterexample to my guessed candidate for I. I seem to be getting a huge error log on running this code, could anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
s = SolverFor("HORN")
I = Function('I', IntSort(), BoolSort()) 
x, x2 = Ints('x x2') 
s.set("produce-proofs", True)
s.add( ForAll( [x] ,Implies( x == 0  , I(x))) ) 
s.add( ForAll( [x, x2]  , Implies ( And( I(x), x2 == x + 1 , x < 5) ,  I(x2) )  ) ) 
s.add( ForAll( [x] ,Implies( And( I(x), Not(x < 5) ) , x == 5 ) ) ) 
s.add( ForAll( [x],  And( Implies( I(x) , (x == 2) ), Implies( (x == 2) , I(x) ) ) ) ) #Adding guessed invariant here!
assert unsat == s.check()
print(s.proof())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a couple of mistakes in the script; perhaps this dates back from a while ago with a different version of z3? In any case, the following goes through with z3 version 4.8.14:

```py
from z3 import *

s = SolverFor("HORN")
I = Function('I', IntSort(), BoolSort())
x, x2 = Ints('x x2')
s.set("proof", True)
s.add( ForAll( [x] ,Implies( x == 0  , I(x))) )
s.add( ForAll( [x, x2]  , Implies ( And( I(x), x2 == x + 1 , x < 5) ,  I(x2) )  ) )
s.add( ForAll( [x] ,Implies( And( I(x), Not(x < 5) ) , x == 5 ) ) )
s.add( ForAll( [x],  And( Implies( I(x) , (x == 2) ), Implies( (x == 2) , I(x) ) ) ) ) #Adding guessed invariant here!
print(s.check())
```

Unfortunately it prints:

```
unknown
```

This means the solver wasn't able to determine if the input is satisfiable or not; it gave up and said `unknown`. An earlier version of the solver might've been able to solve this successfully, providing an unsatisfiability proof, or a model should it be satisfiable.

I recommend tracking down where you got this example from and find out which version of z3 they were using. Going back to that version might help you make progress. Or, if you think the problem should be solvable as is, you can file a bug report at https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/issues

Comment: Thanks, but I was actually looking for sth slightly different. Suppose the CHC clauses I have are (let I(x) be an unknown predicate) be: x = 0 -> I(x) , x < 5 /\ I(x) /\ x' = x + 1 -> I(x') and I(x) /\ x >= 5 -> x = 5. Now instead of asking Z3 to solve for I(x) [which it very well can do using s.solve()], I want to feed in some model for I(x) and ask Z3 to check if it's correct or not. So suppose, I want to feed x <2 as a candidate guess for I(x) (it's actually incorrect), how can I ask Z3 to give a counterexample i.e. a value of x satisfying x < 2 but not satisfing the above equations?

Comment: I think that's quite possible, and I don't think you need the horn solver for that purpose. But it's hard to read it off of comments. (Your original question was about getting errors for the script you were trying.) Best to ask a separate question to start a new discussion.

Comment: Above are horn clauses (and they are the horn clauses corresponding to the ones mentioned in the question). I replaced the I(x) guess candidate as x < 2 with $I(x)  <-> x = 2$ as another horn clause hoping to achieve the desired effect. I'll post it as a separate question, tho.